# Javascript conditional order evaluation

Tags: javascript

Can I count on Javascript failing immediately when one condition in an expression results to false?

```
f = {'a':'b'};
if (f.a !== undefined || f.a === 'b') {
  // Is this OK to use, because the second condition will never be evaluated?
}
```

Comment: From what I see in the code your second condition is always evaluated because (f.a!==undefined) equals true.

Comment: The second condition will be evaluated if the first evaluates to false.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, this is known as [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

With an `AND` logical operator, if the first evaluates to `false`, then the second is never evaluated, because the condition knows enough already to be met.

With the `OR` logical operator, if the first one is `false`, it will evaluate the second one. Otherwise if the first is `true` it won't evaluate the second (no need to).

This is also why you see...

```
var a = function(b) {
   b = b || 7;
}
```

Comment: The `b = b || 7;` form is often used as a shorthand way to provide a default value for when b is undefined, on the basis that undefined evaluates as false, but *this doesn't actually work* given that b could hold several other values that all evaluate to false as well (0, null, an empty string, and of course false all evaluate to false). Of course if you're confident that all of those other values should be overridden with a default that's OK...

Comment: @nnnnn It's not perfect, but a lot of the time, it's very useful.

Comment: i think the proper way would be `b = typeof b == "undefined"?7:b;`

Comment: @JVE999 Yeah, that is one way of doing it if you must be certain that you can't handle all *falsey* values in one way.

Comment: @JVE999 Actually I'd say `typeof` is unnecessary there, since you already defined `b` there's no chance of the variable not existing already. So you could just do `== null` and have it check for `null` *and* `undefined` (often they're equatable in this sort of check).