# Multiple conditions in an if statement: Need for validating undefined before checking other conditions

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, multiple-conditions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript conditional order evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891754/javascript-conditional-order-evaluation)

How do multiple conditions in an if-statement pan out?

```
if( bacon && bacon == "crispy") {
   self.eat(bacon);
}
```

If `bacon` doesn't exist, will it still try to check if `bacon` is "crispy"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), so if evaluating the LHS means it doesn't need to evaluate the RHS, it won't.

This is exploited in JavaScript quite frequently...

```
foo = foo || "bar";
```

If `foo` is *truthy* (the LHS), then the condition is known to be `true` and `foo` will be assigned its value (these conditions return the last evaluated expression).

However, if `foo` is *falsy*, it will evaluate the RHS expression, and then assign that result to `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The && operator is a short-circuit operator in JavaScript that will prevent the rest of the statement from being evaluated if the first condition is false.