# Order of evaluation in if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In order to protect my code from accessing undeclared variables I use

```
if (typeof myVar != 'undefined')
```

This works fine but I'd like to stick another if statement in it. Something like converting this:

```
if (typeof myVar != 'undefined'){
    if (myVar == "test"){}
}
```

to this:

```
if (typeof myVar != 'undefined' && myVar == "test")
```

Considering `myVar` may be undefined, is this last code secure in every case of usage and **every browser**?

Is it possible that various statements inside an `if ()` are not evaluated in the order they're written?

Can I assume `myVar == "test"` will **never** be executed if `myVar` is undefined?

Comment: Yes you can. It would be a better approach here to use `if (myVar && myVar == "test")` here.

Comment: Yes && operator is short circuit operator, so other condition will not be checked if first condition is false

Comment: yes, but the code crashes as you try to access an undefined variable

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==` and `!==` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Javascript conditional order evaluation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891754/javascript-conditional-order-evaluation)

Comment: @Saturnix: Code does only crash if you try to access an *undeclared* variable, which you indeed shouldn't.

Comment: myVar can be undeclared and it won't crash if I protect it with typeof - updated the question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can I assume `myVar == "test"` will never be executed if `myVar` is undefined?

Yes. The expression you are testing is a [logical AND expression](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11) and the order of evaluation of the two operands is specified:

> The production *LogicalANDExpression* `:` *LogicalANDExpression* `&&` *BitwiseORExpression* is evaluated as follows (emphasis added):
>
> - Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LogicalANDExpression*.
> - Let *lval* be GetValue(*lref*).
> - If ToBoolean(*lval*) is false, **return *lval*.**
> - Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *BitwiseORExpression*.
> - Return GetValue(*rref*).

That basically says evaluate the first operand, if the result of that evaluation is `false`, the entire expression is `false`, and the second operand is never evaluated.

Answer (score 6):

Yes if you are using **&&** operator then if first condition is **false** then second will never test.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is OK.

In javascript, the precedence is as below:

`typeof` > `!=/==` > `&&`

For `a && b`, `b` will never be executed when `a` is false.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (typeof myVar != 'undefined' && myVar == "test")
```

The expression is evaluated left to right so it will [short circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) if `myVar` is `undefined` (myVar will not be compared to "test")

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use the && operator, the conditions that you pass in will be evaluated in the order that they were passed in.

In your case:

```
if (typef myVar != 'undefined' && myVar == 'test')
```

When the program enters this if statement, it first checks if the variable type is undefined, if it returns true, it continues to the second argument and checks if myVar has a value of 'test'. Even if myVar == 'test', the if statement will evaluate the value of false && true, which returns true. Only if both conditions return true, the code block will get executed, because the expression will be evaluated as true (true && true).

If the first condition

```
typeof myVar != 'undefined'
```

returns false, the second condition will never get evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

Very Important!
Use

```
if (myVar !== undefined)
```

This means that is no way that myVar will pass if it had any assignment before.

AND DONT USE `'undefined'` THIS IS A SIMPLE STRING!

Good luck!

Comment: `var myVar = undefined` is not an assignment?

Comment: The `typeof` operator DOES RETURN A SIMPLE STRING!