# Check values in a Sequelize models before inserting a new record to other model in typescript

Tags: typescript, post, sequelize.js

I have three Sequelize models as follows:

```
User (userId, userName, moneyInWallet)
Product (productId, productName, price)
Purchase (purchaseId, buyingUser, quantity, dateOfPurchase)
```

I now wanted to write a 'post' method in typescript to insert a record into 'Purchase' model only if the 'moneyInWallet' of a user in 'User' model is greater than 'price' of the product from 'Product' model like:

```
purchaseController.post('/add/',
    (req: Request, res: Response) => {
/* logic here*/
})
```

Can someone please help me with this...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just decode your data from post req [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters)

then find user and product. check your logic and create new Purchase.
send back what you need usually id of new item

it will be something like this:

```js
const {User, Product, Purchase} = require("/path/to/models");
app.use(express.json());  // to decode post body json data

purchaseController.post('/add/',
    async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      try{
        const { 
          userId, 
          productId,
          quantity,
        } = req.body;

        const user = await User.findOne({where: {userId}});
        const product = await Product.findOne({where: {productId}})

        if(user && product && user.moneyInWallet > product.price * quantity){
            const {purchaseId} = await Purchase.create({
              //purchaseId - should by autocreated
              buyingUser: userId 
              quantity 
              // dateOfPurchase - should by autocreated 
            })
            if(purchaseId == undefined){
              res.status(500)// or some other bad code
              res.send("unable to create purchase record in database")
            } else {
              res.json({
                purchaseId
              })
            }
        } else {
            res.send("user product not finded or user don't have enough money")
        } 
      } catch(error){
          res.status(500)// or some other bad code
          res.send(error.message)
      }
})
```

Comment: It would be a bit faster to use `Promise.all()` to fetch the user and product concurrently. `const [user, product] = await Promise.all([
  User.findOne({where: {userId}}),
  Product.findOne({where: {productId}}),
])`

Comment: @doublesharp yes. i know but if some one ask about help with this, i think is better to not complicate solution.

Comment: Makes sense, I was just adding more info in the comments if they wanted it. You do have a bug in your answer, it's missing 'await' before `Purchase.create()`.

Comment: @robert, Thank you for your reply. I tried it and getting the following error. Could you please help me with it?   `Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside 
of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

Comment: @robert, Thanks for your constant help. But, I am getting this error now `Cannot read property 'moneyInWallet' of null` at the line `if(user && product && user.moneyInWallet > product.price * quantity).`

Comment: this is not possible. if user is null then user.moneyInWallet is never checked. [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891754/javascript-conditional-order-evaluation)